# Implement Intrusion Prevention System from SNORT IDS

Tags: snort, intrusion-detection

I have currently installed Snort 2.9.0.4 on Fedora 14 . The Snort IDS Mode is running perfectly, I want to Implement an IPS from the Snort IDS.. I am completely New to linux environment.

Answer (score 1):

You configure the snort config file such that logs are entered in a SQL database (create database in sql) and use BASE, so by that you can view all logs in customized manner.